# How can I get an entire 2D Bezier Curve Object to accurately curve over a bezier curve modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying to take a glasses object that I created with a 2D Bezier curve and then bend them over a bezier curve via object modifier to make them the actual shape of the of the glasses rather than a flat, projected 2d version of the shape. Problem is that it's only curving the beveled edge of the object, not the rest of it. I am still a novice and would really appreciate the help!

[image: Glasses Cutout]
Here's how it's rendering from the side. Only the beveled edge of the object is actually getting brought forward on the y-axis.

Thanks again, I really appreciate any help I can get.

EDIT: Here's the .blend
[image]

The settings I'm using on the "Glasses Front" object are the default "Curve" Deform modifier settings, using the "Glasses Shape Curve" bezier curve as the curve and using the X-axis for the Deform Access. Running Blender 2.73.

Comment: It's not clear from your description the main thing: "...it's only curving the beveled edge of the object...", probably this is about strange behaviour of **Curve Modifier**. It'll really help if you post the modifier options and copy of the blend file to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: I added the .blend file link and my Curve modifier options. Hope that helps!

Comment: The whole mesh was stretched by Y axis actually; only the effect was too small to see it. To make your `Glasses Shape Curve` object edit mesh as desired, [subdivide your curve](https://imgur.com/a/FmDN4). With some tweaking you'll get result as on pic.2. And you'll really want to convert your glasses to mesh and make retopo for it, but it's another story. I can write a more detailed answer on that later on if this result is good enough for you.